# Flash AS2 animation continues at odd point if movie is loaded and unloaded quickly?

Tags: flash, animation, actionscript-2

I have a flash file that has three main buttons on top. When a button is clicked the timeline moves to a that frame (designated with a label) that loads in a particular external SWF corresponding with the button. Those movies are loaded into the same empty movieclip called "presentation" using:

```
loadMovie("splash.swf","presentation");
```

In one of the external loaded SWF's there is a tween animation (on first frame using TweenLite), that takes place upon loading the SWF. The issue is that when I click a button and go to another frame (which loads another SWF) mid-way through that animation, and come back to that same page with the animation. The animations starts mid-way as if it was running in the back, such as fading in things that shouldn't be faded in yet, etc..? Any clue as to why?

**EDIT:** Maybe this is the cause? The animation code in the first frame of the loaded SWF:

```
//Animate the bouquet
var bFadeIn:Tween = new Tween(bouquet,"_alpha",Back.easeInOut,0,100,1,true); //106.95

bFadeIn.onMotionFinished = function() {
    for(var i=1; i < 12; i++) {
        TweenLite.to(bouquet["olddot"+i], 1, {_x:96.25, _y:94.05, _alpha: 0, ease:Back.easeInOut});
    }

    TweenLite.to(bouquet.chip, 1, {_alpha:0, delay:1, onComplete:newDotsAnimate}); 
}

function newDotsAnimate() {
    TweenLite.to(bouquet.phone,1, {_alpha:100, ease:Back.easeOut, delay:.3});
    bouquet.phone._visible = true;
    TweenLite.to(bouquet.newdot1, 1, {_alpha:100, _x:127.95, _y:23, ease:Back.easeOut, delay:1});
    TweenLite.to(bouquet.newdot2, 1, {_alpha:100, _x:226.45, _y:101.50, ease:Back.easeOut, delay:1});
    TweenLite.to(bouquet.newdot3, 1, {_alpha:100, _x:188.70, _y:216.60, ease:Back.easeOut, delay:1});
    TweenLite.to(bouquet.newdot4, 1, {_alpha:100, _x:59.95, _y:216.90, ease:Back.easeOut, delay:1});
    TweenLite.to(bouquet.newdot5, 1, {_alpha:100, _x:26.95, _y:100.95, ease:Back.easeOut, delay:1});

    TweenLite.to(bouquet_instructions,1,{_alpha:100}); //fade in the instructions, then fade them out
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The animations starts mid-way as if it was running in the back? Any clue as to why?

Your loaded SWF is going to stop in place where you left it.  Going back to the frame showing it will cause it to resume where it left off unless you called gotoAndStop(1).  This is because the SWF isn't being unloaded and reloaded every time you navigate on the timeline.

Your best bet, if possible, is to create a cleanup() or hide() method for your loaded SWF(s) that gets called whenever the main SWF navigates away from them.  That way your loaded SWF content can disable itself (stop playing sounds, stop playing on the timeline, etc).  By implementing this function themselves the loaded SWFs take responsibility for their "reset" conditions, and all the loading SWF has to do is call "loadedSWF.cleanup()".

Comment: I've edit my question a bit for this. I guess I'm wondering since I read on the Kirupa forums that if a movie is loaded into the same empty location, then it should automatically unload the current movie playing? Would this stop the previous movie from playing or would I have to manually unload and stop the movie using a cleanup method that you suggested?

Comment: If you use a Flash keyframe to create a MovieClip (not AS2) and then navigate to a different frame where the MovieClip has no frames - then yes, that clip will be removed and stopped.  You loaded a new SWF, however, and attached that to the timeline.  I think that affects your situation.  Because it was added via a loader and not instanced from a keyframe it is never removed because of timeline navigation.  I admit I have not worked extensively in AS2 for a couple years, so I may be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because it's still running in the background. what does your play event look like? are you doing a "gotoAndPlay(1)" on load?

if you want it to not do that, one easy way would be to hook up a stop event to the button press. so, like this (it's been a few years since i've used as2, so bear with me here):

```
button2.onMouseUp(){
       loadedMovie.gotoAndStop(1);
}
```

an even cleaner way would be to write a function that stopped all of the external movies when moving from one to the other.

then, when you go back, your play event should start correctly.